# Visual C# how to merge two 1D string[] arrays into one 2D string[,] array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been diligently studying the help file and all similar questions, but was not able to get to a simpler solution. Yet I think there should be.
I have two `string[]` arrays and I need to merge them into one 2D array.

Here is the code I got to:

```
    public static string[,] GetStructure(string FilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            xliff = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(FilePath));
            XNamespace ns = "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";
            string[] ids = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "st").Select(e => e.Parent.Attribute("id").Value).ToArray();
            string[] elements = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "st").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();

            string[,] mergedarray = new string[ids.Length, 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                mergedarray[i, 0] = ids[i];
                mergedarray[i, 1] = elements[i];
            }

            return mergedarray;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion to make this merging simpler?

Comment: Does it have to be a ``string[,]`` array or can it be a ``Dictionary<string, string>``?

Comment: Why do you think your way needs to be simpler? For me it looks simple, clean and has only 10 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq.

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, ids.Length).ToList();
range.ForEach(i => { mergedarray[i, 0] = ids[i]; mergedarray[i, 1] = elements[i]; });
```

Maybe there is a better Linq statement

Comment: `ForEach` is not a valid method for `Enumerable.Range` though.

Comment: You can convert range to list.

`var range = Enumerable.Range(0, ids.Length - 1).ToList();
            range.ForEach(i => { mergedarray[i, 0] = ids[i]; mergedarray[i, 1] = elements[i]; });`

Comment: Great. See edit, the upper bound of the `Range` however must be `ids.Length` to include all elements.

Comment: the mergedarray has a zero based index. in your for-loop you wrote `i < ids.Length`. `ids.Length - 1` should be correct. Am I right?